# Setting bar chart to categorical in IronPython

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I am using the following code on a bar chart to switch the dimension.

```
            myChart.XAxis.Expression = "[Sales]"
            myChart.BarWidth = 100
```

As soon as I do this, the bars become too skinny. This is because the bar chart axis mode automatically changes to "Continuous" (this setting is found in the Category Axis --> Settings --> Axis mode in the bar chart properties) when you alter the XAxis with ironpy

How would I adjust the bar chart to be "Categorical"?

API library refers to this but I can't figure out how to call this correctly to change the axis mode. I think its only a get?: http://stn.spotfire.com/dxp/html/P_Spotfire_Dxp_Application_Visuals_Axis_AxisMode.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is an interesting one :) you would think that it's a property, but actually to switch an expression between Categorical and Continuous, it's a matter of adding or removing angle braces (`<>`) respectively.

so you could have:

```
if my_var = "continuous": 
    my_expression = "[Sales]"
else:
    my_expression = "<[Sales]>"
```

or if you want to be terse:

```
my_expression = "[Sales]" if my_var = "continuous" else "<[Sales]>"
```